# Saving a page/static block triggers an tinymce error and I can´t switch from HTML to text

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, tinymce

I have a up to date Magento System. But for some reason when I am in the backend and want to edit a page or a static block, I cant switch from the HTML view to the text/visual view. If I click the (sry, dont know how it is in english ) "switch on editor", this is what my console says
[image: firebug console error]

and when I save a page this occurs:
[image: saving page error]

**What I tried:** 
I uploaded the js files from a fresh magento installation but this didnt help.

I uploaded the tinymce plugin folder from a fresh magento - didnt help.

Anyone an idea what I can try / how to fix this?